# With php strftime can I define %p?

Tags: php, strftime

With some locale settings, `%p` returns an empty string. I would prefer in those cases to have it return either AM or PM even when that is not correct for the language.

The usage case is calendar of events where the user can choose to override the default and specify they want 12 hour time. It would make the code a lot easier if at the beginning of the class, I could detect if `%p` returns a localized string or empty, and define it as AM or PM when empty.

-- EDIT --

```
<?php
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'ru_RU.UTF8');
print(strftime('%l:%M %p %Z', time()));
?>
```

In many locales, such as `ru_RU`, `%p` returns a useless empty string. When a translation for AM or PM is not defined, I want to define it as AM or PM. Just like my question before the edit specified.

Comment: can you provide you provide your code as [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Damn the comment interface sucks, hit return for another line and it submits. I'll add it in a sec

Comment: $start = strftime($dformat, $node->start);
    $search = array('/^12:00 ' . $this->AM . '/', '/^00:00$/', '/^12:00 ' . $this->PM . '/', '/^12:00$/');
    $replace = array('12:00 ' . $this->getString('Midnight'), '00:00 ' . $this->getString('Midnight'), '12:00 ' . $this->getString('Noon'), '12:00 ' . $this->getString('Noon'));
    $start = preg_replace($search, $replace, $start);
    $event->setAttribute('start', $start);

$dformat can be be several things, some of which include %p and $this->getstring internationalizes Midnight and Noon.

Comment: And apparently the mini markdown in comments doesn't understand 4 spaces means code.

Comment: btw I'm not looking for a work around, I can write a function in the class that does a workaround. I'm looking for a way that %p can return AM or PM in locales such as RU_ru.utf8 where it currently returns a 0 length empty string so that I won't need to use a hackish function to do what strftime should do and may already have a way to do.

Comment: add to the question as edit, don't post code in comment!

Comment: Well okay. The issue is that the string is dynamically generated - e.g. whether it is 24 or 12 hour, whether it should have time zone abbreviation, etc. - I just wrote a wrapper function in the class that parses the generated format and compensates for locales where %p returns an empty string. Good enough for now, would be nice to be able to assign AM/PM to %p when the string is empty but I don't see a way.

Comment: Why are you still commenting? edit your question and add these additional information with code.

Comment: Still commenting because there is enough information in the question without code. It adequately asks what I want to do.

Comment: What you want to do is not enough, rather it also needs what you have tried. Never try to comment on comment, try to give effect on question first. It seems you have a good rep to understand the community. It is not expected from you, you are not a newbie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing that comes to mind, and this may be more of a bandaid solution, but is to check in `$dformat` for `%p`

**EDITED SOLUTION**

If there are varied forms of formatting as I gathered in the comments, than perhaps it's best to actually interpolate your own %p if %p renders an empty string so this solution may work for you:

```
$check_for_empty_string = false;
if (preg_match("@%p@", $dformat)) {
    if (strftime('%p', $node->start) == '') {
        // get 24 hours
        $hour = strtotime('%H', $start);
        if ($hour >= 12) {
            // it's PM
            $dformat = preg_replace("@%p@", $this->PM, $dformat);
        } else {
            $dformat = preg_replace("@%p@", $this->AM, $dformat);
        }
    }
}

$start = strftime($dformat, $node->start);

$search = array(
    '/^12:00 ' . $this->AM . '/', 
    '/^00:00$/', '/^12:00 ' . $this->PM . '/', 
    '/^12:00$/'
);
$replace = array(
    '12:00 ' . $this->getString('Midnight'), 
    '00:00 ' . $this->getString('Midnight'), 
    '12:00 ' . $this->getString('Noon'), 
    '12:00 ' . $this->getString('Noon')
);
$start = preg_replace($search, $replace, $start);
$event->setAttribute('start', $start);
```

Comment: I have my own bandaid that works, I was hoping there was a way to define %p in cases where it isn't defined. Your bandaid though is nicer than mine, mine involved a split command and two calls to strftime on either side of the %p.

Answer (score 2):

```
private function TwelveHourHack($dformat, $ts) {
  if($this->safeTwelve) {
    return strftime($dformat, $ts);
  }
  $dformat = preg_replace('/%p/', date('A', $ts), $dformat);
  return strftime($dformat, $ts);
}
```

That's what I finally ended up doing. $this->safeTwelve is boolean set at class initiation by looking at

```
strlen(strftime('%p', $now))
```

Comment: Cool, it's probably better to put it in a private function to keep the code cleaner anyhow, that's what I would've done.